# Exponential growth model using SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I'm trying to implement the exponential growth model using SymPy.

```
n = Function('N')
t = symbols('t')
r = 1.7

eq = Eq(n(t).diff(t), r*n(t))
sol = dsolve(eq, ics={n(0): 10})
plot(sol.rhs, t, title='Exponential growth', xlabel='Time', ylabel='Population')
t = np.linspace(0,50,5)
```

Here is my output:

[image]

Why does the population seem to start at 0? How can I fix this to start at for example 10?

Answer (score 0):

It does start at 10 but exponential growth gets big very quickly so your plot has a `1e9` vertical scale which makes 10 look very small. This is why things that grow exponentially are usually plotted on a logarithmic scale. Try reducing the xlimits or plotting with `yscale="log"` to get a better view.